# Docker httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded - Only when using non-default httpd.conf

Tags: apache, docker

Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.4.41
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
COPY ./key.pem /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key
COPY ./cert.pem /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt
COPY ./sites.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

For some reason, if I add my own httpd.conf, I received the following error:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 test1
AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
```

What's weirder, is that `my-httpd.conf` is coming straight from the image itself (unmodified) using this command:

```
docker run --rm httpd:2.4.41 cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf > my-httpd.conf
```

So as far as I can tell, I am overwriting the default httpd.conf with an exact copy.

Just in case there is any doubt, if I do not have `COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` in my Dockerfile, the image runs perfectly fine.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You should check if `LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so` is uncommented in `httpd.conf` file. If it is you should convert `httpd.conf` from UTF-16 format to UTF-8 format.